# simple apply to concat pandas-columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

How can I make this program work? The result should be concatenated integers:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5), 'B': range(5, 10)})
f = lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y)
d[['A', 'B']].apply(f, axis = 1)
```

Thx & kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In apply with `DataFrame` and `axis=1` each loop generate `Series`:

```
f = lambda x: str(x.A) + str(x.B)
a = d[['A', 'B']].apply(f, axis = 1)
```

Very similar is possible convert both columns to `string`s first:

```
f = lambda x: x.A + x.B
a = d[['A', 'B']].astype(str).apply(f, axis = 1)
```

You can check processing by custom function:

```
def f(x):
    print (x)
    print (x.A)
    print (x.B)
    return str(x.A) + str(x.B)

a = d[['A', 'B']].apply(f, axis = 1)

A    0
B    5
Name: 0, dtype: int64
0
5
A    1
B    6
Name: 1, dtype: int64
1
6
A    2
B    7
Name: 2, dtype: int64
2
7
A    3
B    8
Name: 3, dtype: int64
3
8
A    4
B    9
Name: 4, dtype: int64
4
9
```

But better/faster is join with `+`, but first cast numeric columns to `string`s:

```
a = d['A'].astype(str) + d['B'].astype(str)
```

---

```
print (a)
0    05
1    16
2    27
3    38
4    49
dtype: object
```

Comment: What I don't get is, what am I handing over to the lambda-function "f" from d[['A', 'B']]? Columns = Pandas-Series / Lists or the single elements of d.A and d.B?

Comment: Not sure if understand, so was added custom function for better explanation.

Comment: Many thanks, using your customs-func made it clear even to me.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something simpler, like:

```
d['A'].apply(str) + d['B'].apply(str)
```